# Display only newest comments from author

Tags: wordpress, comments

Hi I have code to display comment list in my template. my question is possible to display only newest comment from the author. Example: If author B has made 3 comment in same post, i want to display just newest comment from author B and exclude/hidden the other comments has made by author B.

Here my code :

```
    <table class="table table-striped">  
        <thead class="btn-primary bottom-margin">   
            <tr>
                <th>Form ID</th>
                <th>Subject</th>  
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>  
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <?php  $args = array(
                'status' => 'approve',
                'number' => 0,
                'order' => 'DESC'
            );
                $comments = get_comments($args);
                foreach($comments as $comment) : $count++;?>

            <?php  $post_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'ticket_system',
                'p' => $comment->comment_post_ID,
                'posts_per_page' => 50
                );

                $posts = get_posts($post_args);
                foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="col-md-2 flags"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "idticket",$single = true); ?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-6 flags"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></td>  
                        <td class="col-md-2 flags"><?php echo $comment->comment_author;?></td>
                        <td class="col-md-2 flags"><?php echo $comment->comment_date;?></td>
                    </tr> 


            <?php  endforeach;
            endforeach; ?>      

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "GROUP BY" clause to get the newest comment from each author and the function "get_comments()" does not take a parameter for "group by". (Supported parameters are listed [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)).

You will have to query the comments table via get_results() function and pass the MySql query so code will look like this:

```
$table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix; // Get the WP table prefix in your database
$table_name = "comments"; // Table name we need to query
$table = $table_prefix . $table_name; // prefixing the table name
$comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM " . $table . " where comment_approved=1  order by comment_date desc)c group by comment_author order by comment_date desc");
```

Now in $comments you have the newest comment from each author and you can loop through as you want.

Please note I am grouping the comments by author name you can do it for the "comment_author_email" or being very specific by "comment_author_IP".

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can make change in the SELECT statement the way you want